How much energy does it need to keep a car warm?
If I sit in an parked electric car on a cold day I can measure (using dashboard info) how much power is going into the heater, for example to keep the car at a constant 20 degrees when it's zero degrees outside. But if the car is moving the heat loss will be greater. I can't use the power meter when the car is moving since it will be dominated by the driving motor(s).
So, if it takes, say, 500W to maintain the car at 20 deg above ambient when stationery on a windless day, is it possible to calculate roughly how much power is required when moving at 50 (or 100) kph? (Assume simple weather conditions, e.g. no solar gain, no rain, and a given surface area, say 15 m2)
50 years ago I probably knew enough thermodynamics to attempt a calculation myself, but it's all forgotten now.

the correct term is km/h, not kph

The energy input will be measured as power over time, you state power only. "So, if it takes, say, 500W to maintain the car at 20 deg" so is that 500W for 1 second, 1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day etc?

@SolarMike, 500W is the steady-state power required to maintain the temperature when the car is stationary, whether it's for ten minutes or an hour (or more). The total energy needed to get it warm in the first place will be a different measure, but I'm not asking about that.

It will depend a lot on the level of direct sunlight. A car is very a similar to a greenhouse. Some waste heat from the motor and batteries will also contribute intentionally or not. I think this will be hard to measure in isolation.

Cant you run the car with heating on and off and see the difference in the power meter when its running?

@SolarMike, (1) "The energy input will be measured as power over time ..." No, it's energy = power x time. (2) "... so is that 500 W for 1 second, 1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day, etc.? It would be all for of the above.

@SamiSafarini, only if was posssible to make two journeys on the same road at exactly the same speed in the same weather conditions. Not very practical! and I would expect the heater power to be only 10-20% of driving power so error margins would be considerable.

It might be interesting to gather data while parked on days with different average wind speeds in order to get a handle on the relationship between air flow and power level.
